# How to create a a multi-select nested dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, angular

Using Angular, I want to create a multi-select nested dropdown menu. Similar to this:

https://codepen.io/sathomas/pen/VpJeEo (see the "multiple with search" example)

html:

```
<nested-select options="vm.populations" placeholder="Search items" label="Permanently Open"
    multiple collapsible fixed-menu allow-select-all></nested-select>
```

controller:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize','ngMaterial', 'ngMdIcons'])

.controller('myCtrl', [function myCtrl () {
    var vm = this;

    // static collection for test/demo
    vm.populations = [
        { text: "Item 1" }, 
        { text: "Item 2",
            children: [
                { text: "Item 2.1" }
            ]
        }, 
        { text: "Item 3",
            children: [
                { text: "Item 3.1",
                    children: [
                        { text: "Item 3.1.1",
                            children: [
                                { text: "Yet Another Item 3.1.1.1" }
                            ]
                        },
                        { text: "Item 3.1.2" }
                    ]
                }, 
                { text: "Item 3.2",
                    children: [
                        { text: "Item 3.2.1" },
                        { text: "Item 3.2.2" }
                    ]
                },
                { text: "Item 3.3" }
            ]
        }
    ];
}])
```

But the above code is done using angularJs. Is there an Angular Implementation to do this? I have looked at the material library, but there is no example that has nested multi selectable items. https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples